# symfony : Form with one parameter

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, parameter-passing

I have a form, and I want to pass it one parameter which must use to fill a widget.

I pass the parameter in my url :

```
url_for('myModule/new?parameter='.$myParam)
```

I have tried to take the parameter in my action and display it in my tamplate, but it doesn't work.

Action :

```
$this->param = $request->getParameter('parameter');
```

Template :

```
echo param;
```

But I can't recover it in my form.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameter is an attribute of the object, you can do :

```
$object = new Class();
$object->setAttribute($request->getParameter('myParam'));

$form = new ClassForm($object);
```

Comment: Or if you need a form option `$form = new ClassForm($object, array("myoption" => $request->getParameter("myOption")));`

Answer (score 5):

If this parameter is needed for initializing your form then you could do it like this (keep in mind that you should always validate user input)

```
  public function executeNew($request)
  {
    $formOptions = array('parameter' => $request->getParameter('parameter'));
    $this->form = new MyForm(array(), $formOptions);
    // Then within your form you access it with:
    // $parameter = $this->options['parameter'];
    // or even better:
    // $parameter = $this->getOption('parameter');
    ... more code ...
  }
```

If the parameter is submitted as part of the form then you should bind it like this:

```
  public function executeNew($request)
  {
    $this->form = new MyForm();
    if ( $request->isMethod('post') ) {
      $this->form->bind($request->getPostParameters());
    }
    ... more code ...
  }
```

Please refer to the Symfony's [Forms in Action](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation) for more on how to create and use forms.

**Edit**: Added `$this->getOption('parameter')` to the code example.

Comment: I have tried your first solution with $formOptions. But xDebug call me : 'parameter' => null. However I have passed something in my URL. I don't understand why.

Comment: When you call $this->getOption('parameter') within the form's configure method, what does it return?

Comment: I have an error : "Call to undefined method sfPartialView::getOption". The problem doesn't comme from the method to recover the value, the problem is the parameter isn't passed to the template.

Comment: It seems to me that I misunderstood your question. Do you use the Symfony Forms framework or with 'form' you meant plain HTML forms?

Comment: @lunohodov I tried to get the option with `$this->getOption('parameter')` and didn't work. Looks like the right way to do it is get it from the _Form_ instance like this: `$this->form->getOption('parameter')`

Comment: @RickyCheers Thanks, however I already state this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a route for this URL in your routing.yml and add your parameter to this route.

for example:

```
mymoduel_new:
   url:    myModule/new/:paramter/
   param:  { module: myModule, action: new }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it to the form constructor, both the constructors of `sfForm` and `sf{Propel,Doctrine}Form` take a parameter called `$options`, use that. Store the value in a private property, so you can use in in the form's `configure` method.